# react-query useQuery skipping entries when fetching asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-query

In a high level overview I am building a tinder like app functionality. Where in my example, 4 entries are fetched from my DB, the user is shown one at a time and can click a like or a dislike button. Each button click triggers some asynchronous functions for writing the event to my DB. Once the last entry that was fetched is clicked I need to go and fetch the next 4 entries in my DB.

**MY COMPONENT**

```
export const HomePage: React.FC = () => {
  const { user } = useUser()
  const userId = user?.id
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState<number | null>(0)
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0)

  const [url, setUrl] = useState(
    `/api/swipes/get-users/?userId=${user?.id}&skip=${skip}`
  )

  const getUsers = async (url: string) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url)
    return data
  }

  const { error, data, isLoading, refetch } = useQuery(
    ['userSwipeData', url],
    () => getUsers(url),
    {
      enabled: !!user?.id,
    }
  )

  const handleRefetchUsers = () => {
    setCurrent(0)
    setUrl(
      `/api/swipes/get-users/?userId=${user?.id}&skip=${
        skip + FETCH_USERS_PAGINATION_LIMIT
      }`
    )
    refetch()
    setSkip(skip + FETCH_USERS_PAGINATION_LIMIT)
  }

  const handleSwipe = async (e: any) => {
    if (current === null || !data) return

    const { value } = e.target
    await handleSwipeType(value, data?.users[current].id)
  }

  const handleSwipeType = async (type: string, id: string) => {
    const values = {
      userSwipeOn: id,
      currentUser: userId,
    }

    // if (type === 'YES') {
    //   if (current && data?.users[current]?.isMatch) {
    //     await axios.post('/api/swipes/create-match', values)
    //     alert('You have a match!')
    //   }

    //   await axios.post('/api/swipes/like', values)
    // } else {
    //   await axios.post('/api/swipes/dislike', values)
    // }
    if (current === data.users.length - 1) {
      handleRefetchUsers()
    } else {
      setCurrent(current! + 1)
    }
  }

  if (isLoading || current === null) return <Box>Fetching users...</Box>
  if (error) return <Box>An error has occurred </Box>
  if (data && !data?.users.length) return <Box>No more users for now</Box>

  return (
    <Box>
      <h1>Current User: {data?.users[current].email}</h1>
      <Flex>
        <button value="NO" onClick={handleSwipe}>
          NO
        </button>
        <button value="YES" onClick={handleSwipe}>
          YES
        </button>
      </Flex>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

The problem I am facing is that in this current state when the `handleRefetchUsers()` function triggers it works as expected. However, if I am to uncomment all the asynchronous code which I need to run on every click to document the event, once the `handleRefetchUsers()` trigger I notice it is skipping 4 entries every time it runs. I'm really at a loss as to why because the check for a final entry should only run after the async code has finished. Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `refetch` doesn't wait for `setUrl` to actually update the url

You shouldn't really base one state on another state

To fix it I would replace

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState(
  `/api/swipes/get-users/?userId=${user?.id}&skip=${skip}`
)
```

with

```
const url = /api/swipes/get-users/?userId=${user?.id}&skip=${skip}`
```

and remove `refetch` entirely. react-query will refetch anyway because the url changed

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that could be improved, but your main issue is that setState is async. So when you use `setUrl` and then call `refetch`, refetch is still looking at the old `url` value.

I think a cleaner way would be to use `refetch` inside an effect, that has `current` and `skip` in the dependency array.

Also, `url` is a derived state, so it doesn't really need its own state. And you should also be using an arrow function when a new state relies on the previous state - again because setState is async, and it's possible that you are referencing an old state.

```
const buildUrl = (user, skip) => user?.id ? `/api/swipes/get-users/?userId=${user?.id}&skip=${skip}` : ''

export const HomePage: React.FC = () => {
  const { user } = useUser()
  const userId = user?.id

  const [current, setCurrent] = useState<number>(0) // current page
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0)

  const getUsers = async (url: string) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url)
    return data
  }

  const { error, data, isLoading, refetch } = useQuery(
    ['userSwipeData', buildUrl(user, skip)],
    () => getUsers(buildUrl(user, skip)),
    {
      enabled: !!user?.id,
    }
  )

  const handleRefetchUsers = () => {
    setCurrent(0)
    setSkip((prev) => prev + FETCH_USERS_PAGINATION_LIMIT)
  }

  const handleSwipe = async (e: any) => {
    if (current === null || !data) return
    const { value } = e.target
    await handleSwipeType(value, data?.users[current].id)
  }

  const handleSwipeType = async (type: string, id: string) => {
    const values = {
      userSwipeOn: id,
      currentUser: userId,
    }

    if (type === 'YES') {
      if (current && data?.users[current]?.isMatch) {
        await axios.post('/api/swipes/create-match', values)
        alert('You have a match!')
      }
      await axios.post('/api/swipes/like', values)
    } else {
      await axios.post('/api/swipes/dislike', values)
    }

    if (current === data.users.length - 1) {
      handleRefetchUsers()
    } else {
      setCurrent((prev) => prev + 1)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    refetch()
  }, [current, skip])

  if (isLoading || current === null) return <Box>Fetching users...</Box>
  if (error) return <Box>An error has occurred </Box>
  if (data && !data?.users.length) return <Box>No more users for now</Box>

  return (
    <Box>
      <h1>Current User: {data?.users[current].email}</h1>
      <Flex>
        <button value="NO" onClick={handleSwipe}>
          NO
        </button>
        <button value="YES" onClick={handleSwipe}>
          YES
        </button>
      </Flex>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Comment: FWIW this is the same answer as Konrad, but with some additional thoughts.